# $location.path not working in $mdDialog.show

Tags: angular-material

I used Angular Material (Prompt) in my project. I have to do a post request and after that redirect to another page after (OK) is clicked. I have used $location.path("/ABC") at many places and works fine. But if i use $location.path inside $mdDialog, it is always redirecting to root ("/"). Has anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: Do you have a plunkr?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that yet. Will create soon and share.

Comment: I realised that the issue was not with dialog. I was using $location.path("/ABC?q=") but in the routes I just had "/ABC". Therefore, it couldn't find a matching route and was redirecting it to root(/).